# How many times does the script used in spark pipes gets executed.?

Tags: apache-spark

I tried the below spark scala code and got the output as mentioned below. 
I have tried to pass the inputs to script, but it didn't receive and when i used collect the print statement i used in the script appeared twice.

My simple and very basic perl script first:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print("arguments $ARGV[0] \n"); // Just print the arguments.
```

My Spark code:

```
object PipesExample {
  def main(args:Array[String]){
    val conf = new SparkConf();

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf);

    val distScript = "/home/srinivas/test.pl"
    sc.addFile(distScript)

    val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array("srini"))

    val piped = rdd.pipe(Seq(SparkFiles.get("test.pl")))

    println(" output " + piped.collect().mkString(" "));

  }
}
```

Output looked like this..

```
 output arguments arguments
```

1) What mistake i have done to make it fail receiving the arguments.?
2) Why it executed twice.?

If it looks too basic, please apologize me. I was trying to understand to the best and want to clear my doubts.

Comment: How many instance do you have in your cluster?

Comment: Just one instance. Actually, i am trying it on my local spark installation in ubuntu and did not override any configuration and you can see that, i have not added partitions too.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is executed twice because spark divides your RDD into two partitions and each partition is passed to your external script.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your application couldn't pick test.pl file is, the file is in some node's location. But the application master is created in one of the nodes in cluster. So prolly if the file isn't in that node, it can't pick the file.

You should always save the file in HDFS or S3 to access the external files. Or else pass the HDFS file location through spark command options.